# App index for apps not in Google Play

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

Do you have to put your android app in Google Play for App indexing? Or any downloadable android apps can be indexed once have deep links enabled?

Cheers,
Allen

Comment: Define what you mean by app indexing.  That isn't an industry term, we have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: Hey @GabeSechan, I mean for Google App Indexing. Does the app has to be in Google Play Store?

Comment: I've been doing Android work since 1.6, I've never heard the term.  I think you know what you mean, but nobody else does.

Comment: Well, Its time for some updates.http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To use Google App Indexing, your app must be present in Google Play store.

To enable app indexing, you must declare an association between your website and your app, and for that you must be a verified owner of the app in Google Play and use the same Google account when managing the app in Search Console.

You can see more information on Google App Indexing in their online documentation - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app

Comment: As Google Play policy states that some apps are not allowed in Google play like gambling apps. I guess Google App indexing is not an option for those kind of apps.